# Security team has blocked sending out emails from pipeline jobs

Tags: security, azure-pipelines, email-notifications

I'm using Azure DevOps for running my test automation tests and I intend to sendout the report at the end of test run. However, I cant do that since Helpdesk team has blocked accessing SMTP server since they think they cant monitor those mails and can be sent outside of the organization. So, I'm neither able to install any email report plugins nor can I write a custom script to send out the reports. What can I do?

I have spoken to them and have escalated it to my manager which has been further escalated to higher-ups but there has been no solution to this.

I would like to know how other organizations mitigate this problem, so that I can convey the same to my security team.

P.S: This may not be a programming related question but I'm hoping infrastructure experts can chime in provide their insights.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow can't help you solve issues with internal helpdesk delays.

Comment: You say you can't install email report plugins. Does that include https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GetShifting.GraphEmail ? It allows for sending out email without SMTP but through MS Graph API. Disclaimer: I am the author of the extension.

Comment: @GetShifting yes, any plugin to be added goes through security check and they wouldnt allow any plugins to be installed which they cannot monitor

Comment: Ah I see. Well, the extension also adds the emails it sends to the outbox from the from: address. So it would give them an option to monitor outgoing emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**

If you have them available, you could try using the Microsoft hosted agents in Azure DevOps to send the email. I have not tested to see if this works, but they should be operating under different network restrictions to what your company has configured.

---

**Option 2**

Otherwise, instead of sending an email, if your company uses a tool such as Slack or MS teams, you can integrate Azure pipelines with these messaging services to get reports on your builds in a channel.

- See [Slack integration docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/integrations/slack?view=azure-devops)
- See [Teams integration docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/integrations/microsoft-teams?view=azure-devops)

By default, these integrations only show fairly simple information about a particular build such as pass or fail, but you can build your own scripts to send slack or teams messages to a channel to show which tests are failing for example.

---

**Option 3**

If you have access to build serverless functions in your cloud provider, you could perhaps utilize this to trigger emails, see docs here on sending emails with [Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-send-email?tabs=dotnet). You could then trigger this application via HTTP at the end of a pipeline run, parsing in any details you want to include in the email as parameters.

---

**Option 4**

Depending on your test automation framework that you are using, they may have some type of notification system built in, likely with a paid membership.